# loop though a array then if and then output result?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, if-statement

i have a little problem, in the code below (C#) it loops thought the arrays, it then check if the user_id has a user_post greater than 50, it then write the user_id, the expected outcome is

```
12
13
```

but the actual output is

```
12
12
12
```

whats wrong with the code? I tried a standard for loop but could not get it right?

```
int[] user_id = new int[64];
int[] group_id = new int[64];
int[] user_post = new int[64];

//user 55
user_id[0] = 10;
group_id[0] = 8;
user_post[0] = 4;

//user56
user_id[1] = 11;
group_id[1] = 2;
user_post[1] = 15;

//user57
user_id[2] = 12;
group_id[2] = 2;
user_post[2] = 55;

//user58
user_id[3] = 13;
group_id[3] = 2;
user_post[3] = 56;

foreach (int i in group_id)
{
    if (group_id[i] == 2)
        if (user_post[i] > 50)
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(user_id[i]));
}

Console.WriteLine("Press any key too continue...");
Console.ReadLine();
// continue...
```

Comment: Hmmmm, this isn't a bad question, but I think you can get much faster answers than you get from SO by learning to use the debugging features in your IDE.

Comment: +1 totally agree.. people are taking SO as an alternative to Debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have an if statement that only checks for 2

```
 if (group_id[i] == 2)
```

where as **"i"  is not a counter** instead the element from the foreach loop.
and items at 2 & 3rd position have 2 group id so it alway ends like this:

```
if (group_id[8] == 2) //false
if (group_id[2] == 2) //true
if (group_id[2] == 2) //true
```

---

Instead of that vague code you should have your loop as this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i< 64 ; i++)
{
    if (group_id[i] == 2)
    {
        if (user_post[i] > 50)
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(user_id[i]));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (int i in group_id)
```

is wrong, you must use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < group_id.Length; i++)
```

because with the former you're using the values in `group_id` as indexes of your arrays.

BTW, I'd suggest you to create a class e.g. `Info` like:

```
class Info
{
   public int GroupId {get; set;};
   public int UserId {get; set;};
   public int PostId {get; set;}
}
```

this would allow you to create one array only (i.e. `Info[]`) and avoid possible errors due to different lenghts of the 3 arrays...

Answer (score 0):

You're looping around the wrong array with the for each statement. You should loop using the regular for statement instead like this:

```
    for (int i = 0;i < user_post.Length; i++)
    {
        if (user_post[i] > 50 && group_id[i] == 2)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(user_id[i]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: only problem if i add another e.g.             user_id[5] = 15;
            group_id[5] = 8;
            user_post[5] = 56;
then 15 is also shown and should not be?

Comment: Ya, I've edited the code to only allow group_id 2 to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

in your foreach statement, `i` takes on the values stored in your group_id array - 8, 2, 2, 2

In your `if` and output statements, your are using this value as an index into the arrays

So, your `if` statements end up doing this:

```
if(group_id[8])...
if(group_id[2])...
if(group_id[2])...
if(group_id[2])...
```

You are only examining elements 8 and 2 in your arrays.

Use a `for` loop to iterate through the array indexes

Answer (score 0):

The `for` syntax is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; // incremental variable
     i < 100;   // determining a limit
     ++i)       // increment the variable
```

While `foreach` works like this:

```
foreach (var element        // the element itself, not an index
         in
         elementCollection) // iterating through the collection
```